# Find all Google+ user profiles

Tags: google-plus, google-people-api

Using the Google+ API (people, search method), is it possible to iterate through all Google+ user profiles, i.e., is there a query string that matches all profiles?

Comment: Yes -- the search method accepts a "query string" parameter, but the API documentation says only that it is a "full text" query, and does not specify how the query string determines which profiles are included in the response. Experiments suggest that, for example, the query string "sometext" returns some (but not all) profiles containing displayNames that begin with "sometext". The ideal, generally useful resolution to this question would be a reference to clear documentation of how these searches work -- an informal functional specification, say.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a method of getting a list of Google+ profiles. There are hundreds of millions of profiles so it would be a very resource intensive activity. All of that data would likely be abused to data mine personal information and spam users as well.

[These are the supported methods](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#methods) of interacting with Google+ people and pages.